# PostgreSQL 10 Logical Replication - is it possible to clone tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-10, logical-replication

I have two DB instances with postgresql 10. 
First instance working with wal_level = logical, have ALL TABLE publisher. Second - have subscription to the publisher, described above.

All data from the Master DB tables are successfully sending to the replica.
There is only one issue for me - when my App add a new table on Master - I need to add the same table to the replica (and run REFRESH PUBLICATION).

My question - is there a way for replica DB to create new tables automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Schema changes aren't replicated. You can see that in the documentation, at [Postgresql 10 Logical Replication: Subscription](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication-subscription.html)

The way I handle this is to make all schema changes through a script, and to write the script so that it executes the change commands twice: once on the primary database, and once on the replica.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is only one way to do it :(